# Deference of YCrCb and YUV

Tags: yuv, imaging

I was working on a image format converter, and I was trying to convert YcbCr to RGB. For the testing purpouse I was Looking for YcbCr formated image. Googling it always gives result of YUV, rather yCrCb.

- Are those formats same?
- is there any way to download (or convert) YCbCr Image ?

Comment: [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV): The scope of the terms Y'UV, YUV, YCbCr, YPbPr, etc., is sometimes ambiguous and overlapping. Historically, the terms YUV and Y'UV were used for a specific analog encoding of color information in television systems, while YCbCr was used for digital encoding of color information suited for video and still-image compression and transmission such as MPEG and JPEG. Today, the term YUV is commonly used in the computer industry to describe file-formats that are encoded using YCbCr.

Comment: JPEG are normally store colors as YCbCr