# Difference between YCrCb and YUV - what are the use-cases?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, colors

I can not find a definitive answer to the difference between YUV and YCrCb color spaces.
nVidia’s performance primitives and OpenCV have different functions and constants that indicate
that they are different. For example, [OpenCV’s `cvtColor()` function](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) has separate codes 
`CV_RGB2YCrCb` and `CV_RGB2YUV` — what is the difference? The formula documented for OpenCV’s RGB to YCrCb transformation is given as

[image]

Where the RGB to YUV [as explained on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) is

[image]

Note that the CrCb channels appear to be backwards to UV channels and the
constants are different. The delta’s are just normalization values.

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091813/deference-of-ycrcb-and-yuv) does not really shed light on the details.
Evidently the difference is rooted in [historical differences between analog and digital video](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/387265-Difference-between-YUV-and-YCbCr)? When would I use one versus the other?

Edit: Take a look at the difference between U/CB and V/CR
in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48125095/convert-rgb-image-to-yuv-and-ycbcr-color-space-image-in-opencv-python) and you can see there is a slight difference.

Comment: According to Wikipedia: "Y′CbCr is often confused with the YUV color space, and typically the terms YCbCr and YUV are used interchangeably, leading to some confusion". From experience I can tell there are many more color formats referred as "YUV", with different conversion formulas. You may see YUV as a nickname for describing different things (there is no one YUV color space).

Comment: I am thinking these slightly different YUV formats are tailored for a particular encoding method. The API's I use (NPPI, OpenCV) seem to handle exactly two flavors YUV and YCbCr (which give slight different values). In my case I am converting to NV12 (2 plane version of YUV) which is then encoded as a H264 stream.

Comment: Did you ever reach a conclusion on this? I would love to know the answer

Comment: @Xosrov No conclusion. Just like there are many ways to pick primaries for RGB, I suppose one can choose different bases for YUV flavors. Some may be more amenable to certain encoding schemes. I do not know of any specific reasons in this case.

Comment: Also take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling#Terminology)