# Studying for ImageFormat "YCBCR_P010" of Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I am studying for Camera2 API.
and I do not understand about "YCBCR_P010" of ImageFormat.

as I know, "YCBCR_P010" is support from Android 12.

What is a adventage of "YCBCR_P010"?

If you know something, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: I am unclear what you mean by 'advantage' as it is just a image format (with 10 bit channel values). A bit of searching gives me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/10-bit-and-16-bit-yuv-video-formats and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/recommended-8-bit-yuv-formats-for-video-rendering

Comment: Dear Morrison, Thank you for the reply, I just want to know Good Thing and Bad Thing of the "YCBCR_P010". it is same as, Why "YCBCR_P010" needed? , as I know "YCBCR_P010" based on "YUV420". maybe we can just use "YUV420" but "YCBCR_P010" existed.

Comment: I think the base of your question is why two systems which was also asked/unanswered: [Difference between YCrCb and YUV - what are the use-cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60160142/295004). The links in that question point to historical origins and encoding color differences. Also see: [what is the difference between YUV format and HSV format?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/60732/11232), [Doubts about color spaces and chroma subsampling](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/22800/17568), [Understanding Cb and Cr Components of YCbCr Color Space](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/4849/11232)